# How to filter orders collection by customer phone?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

How I can filter orders collection by customer phone number?
Here is my try:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('customer_phone', array('like' => '%' . $_POST['filter_client_phone'] . '%'))->load();
```

Also how I can filter orders collection by some attribute from shipping information of the order?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAddressFields()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('billing_telephone', $_POST['filter_client_phone'])
```

**Note**: use `shipping_telephone` If you want to filter with shipping address telephone.

Answer (score -1):

You may filter orders collection by using below query 

`$addressTable=Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName("sales/order_address");
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$select=$orders->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('oa'=>$addressTable),'oa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id')
            ->where('oa.address_type=?','shipping')
            ->where('oa.telephone LIKE ?','%' . $_POST['filter_client_phone'] . '%');`